# I need a calender code for API 18

Tags: android, events, calendar

I am quite new to android developing, and I am working on my first app at the moment.
To complete I need a code that will help me learn from it and then write my own.
I need a calendar code with a calendar view that will enable me to create events with a title, description, time and reminders, and that's it pretty much.

I am using eclipse on API 18.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

https://github.com/SimonVT/android-calendarview

or search on github for more libraries